# Visual Studio Code python pip proxy and pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use visual studio code to write some python as I can't handle the memory requirements of pycharm. I'm also working around a corporate proxy, so I've installed cntlm locally to get around this so all requests need to go to 127.0.0.1

I started visual studio code using;

```
<yada yada>\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --proxy-server=http=127.0.0.1:3128
```

so far so good. It they suggests that I'm lacking the pylint module and fails to install it because it's using the wrong proxy;

```
(venv) <yada yada>PycharmProjects/Rosaline/venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip --proxy <corporateproxy>:80 install -U pylint
```

So my first question is why doesn't vsc tell pip to use the right proxy and the second question is why is it installing a linter on a per project basis?

Comment: I don't know about the proxy issue, but for the second question, it's not doing it "*per project*", but [per Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). It does not have its own env like PyCharm, it uses what's available on your system.

Comment: Sorry I might have my terminology mixed up s/project/environment, but why on earth would you want to install a linter in each environment? Surely that's something you want attached to the IDE?

Comment: Well, VS Code is not designed to be *just* for Python, so it needs to be flexible to support other languages. It [can use pylint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting), but it needs to be installed on your system first. You could always install pylint system-wide, and always use that env.

Comment: You want a linter per environment to control the version of the linter you are using. When teams standardize it's often to a specific version that matches their CI system. Otherwise you risk getting different linter messages due to configuration, feature set, bugs, etc. And different teams within the same company can standardize on different versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't try to solve that in VS Code, but on OS level. You can create a global config file for PIP, where you set the proxy for it to use. By that it doesn't matter if you use VS Code or a terminal to run PIP. In a terminal, run:

```
python -m pip config --global set global.proxy https://your-proxy:PORT/
```

For details of pip config, see: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/

Nevertheless, you still need to set proxy correctly in VS Code so that you e.g. can download plugins. VS Code makes use of environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. If you set those correctly, no further configuration is required. Otherwise, you can also explicitly set those settings within VS Code configuration. Just search for proxy in the settings dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use the proxy settings because honestly no one has ever made the feature request to pass them on down to pip. Please open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.